# python wget in ddp module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've a code where i use **"import ddp"** and it throws an error - **"No module named wget"**. Steps i have done so far:

1. Set the path variable as mentioned in different answers
2. Installed wget via pip and it is showing package already in python lib. 
   Checked it too and confirmed.
3. I am using python 2.7, spyder interface and windows, and pip is upgraded to 
   its latest version.
   [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osJNA.png)

Any help on what could be the reason for this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: wget module was not installed so it gives that error. Installed it using `pip` command.

Comment: already done that. ~pip install wget  ..... and it is showing requirement already satisfied (viz, it is already present)

Comment: Try to add `import wget` in python console. If you still get the **No module named wget** error then we can conclude that the module is not successfully installed. If you get other error then add here.